# Swift 3.0 use external enum

Tags: swift3, xcode8

i have started updating my application to swift 3.0, and i got a bunch of errors. Now i am down to one, and i simply can't figure out how to solve it. I have recreated the error with some basic code.

**First a model**

```
struct Model {
var num: Int?

enum TestError : Error {
    case logout
    case showalert
    case bluebackground
}

func testNumber() throws {
    guard let num = num, num > 0 else {
        throw TestError.logout
    }
}
```

}

**and then a controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var modelError : Model.TestError?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            do {
                var test = Model()
                test.num = 0
                try test.testNumber()

            } catch let error as Model.TestError {
                self.modelError = error
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                switch(self.modelError) {
                case .logout: //logout
                case .showalert: //show alert
                case .bluebackground: //set background blue
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

It should be pretty clear to see what is happening. My model contains an enum of type error, which i wonna save in a variable in my viewcontroller to later tackle the error on the main que. This code works perfectly in swift 2.2, but in 3.0 and xcode 8b4 i simply get:

[image]

How can i tackle this problem, so i can work with the error on the main que?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention, when i remove

```
var modelError : Model.TestError?
```

and the associated code, it works perfectly, but then i can tackle the error later

Comment: To be honest, that's a poor design in general. Don't use global state like this

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov well okay, thanks for the feedback. How Would a propper Way to solve my problem be Then?

Comment: I would need to know more about the context before I can suggest something better

Comment: Well in a GCD I need to download some data and decode it in the background, and in case of an error, I need to handle it on the main-thread so I can do some ui-stuff

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate for that to be part of the `viewDidLoad` method, but I could be mistaken. I would have a model class that does that work, and `viewDidLoad` will just ask for it from the model

Comment: This is just some sample code, in my real project its getting called by IBAction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119048/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-magnuskahr).